# Is Kim Dotcom's "Megacard" a viable possibility for bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-credit-card

A week ago Kim Dotcom posted that a Bitcoin Credit Card would be something that he would be keen to support. Apart from Bitcurex, which is a different system and slightly lacking in credability and trustworthiness, I'm interested in a card which works like a credit card but is intrinsically integrated with the BTC system.
Due to the nature of Bitcoin, would a credit card-esque form of payment actually be viable?

 If so, how?

Comment: A debit card is quite obviously not a problem.

A credit card's only difference is that there is someone willing to trust you for an amount of money.

Answer (score 2):

This type of product has been tossed around since at least May 2011 when MagicalTux was the new owner of Mt. Gox.  They no longer discuss it.

BitInstant "leaked" such a Mastercard in Fall 2012.  They claim it is "seeing progress" but there's nothing yet.

There are similar cards.  Peter Schiff's Euro Pacific Bank offers a [gold-backed debit card](http://europacbank.com/our-products/metals-backed-account/) where gold funds are sold when using the debit card to make purchases using fiat.  But that is not available to customers from the U.S.

Comment: Thanks guys. I agree that a debit card is more likely, but what I'm really interested in finding out is how the process behind the transaction would work. I mean, would it be similar to the Euro Pacific Bank Card, if so how can we maintain the decentralised nature of Bitcoin?